# How to use proxy with authentification in Selenium with Chrome WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chrome, proxy

After hours of research I am still not able to use a proxy with authentification (username, password) in selenium using chrome WebDriver.

Here is what I tried:

- using a chrome extension -> not working in headless mode
- using AutoIT -> technically it's working, but for my usecase not good enough
- using chrome options arguments like below, doesn't work:

  chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server=http://" + username + ":" + password + "@" + proxyAndPort);
- fill chrome authentification form with Selenium OOTB functionality: doesn't work because its an OS alert (thats why AutoIT can fill it)

Are there any other possibilities to connect with a proxy with authentification?

EDIT:
After using browsermobproxy, I'm facing the issue that chrome shows me the error "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE". Here's my implementation:

```
    BrowserMobProxyServer proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    
    proxy.setChainedProxy(new InetSocketAddress(myIp, myPort));
    proxy.chainedProxyAuthorization(username, password, AuthType.BASIC);
    proxy.start(0);
        
    chromeOptions.setProxy(ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy));
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

EDIT2:
Use browsermob-proxy version 2.1.5 - everything works fine

Comment: Do you mean you need to authenticate on proxy or you need to use proxy to authenticate on target site?

Comment: To use the proxy I need to enter a username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [set `Proxy-Authorization` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Proxy-Authorization) to the request which are coming from your web browser. I would use [browsermob-proxy](http://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) for handling this.

Here you can find some example of [how to use the proxy with your Selenium test](https://webelement.click/en/http_header_selenium_webdriver_basic_authorization). You need to amend the code from "Create test fish-bone" section so that you have the following `setUpProxy()` method:

```java
public void setUpProxy(){
    proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxy.setChainedProxy(new InetSocketAddress("YOUR_PROXY_HOST", 1234));
    proxy.chainedProxyAuthorization("USER_NAME", "PASSWORD", AuthType.BASIC);
    proxy.start(0);
}
```

- Change `new InetSocketAddress("YOUR_PROXY_HOST", 1234)` to your proxy host and port
- Change `"USER_NAME", "PASSWORD"` to your credentials

The idea is that you configure your selenium to use the proxy which is started by your test code. That proxy in turn is to be configured to use the upstream proxy that you normally use in manual mode.

**P.S.** - Use browsermob-proxy version `2.1.5`

Comment: thanks for your answer. After implementing your suggestion, I'm facing the problem that Chrome shows me ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.
I edited my question with the exact code I use at the moment.

Comment: Solved using browsermob-proxy version 2.1.5

Comment: Oh, I tried with your suggestion (In EDIT).
But I can't connect to internet.
What's the problem???

Comment: There might be many problems here. How do you normally connect to the Internet? Is there any other proxy that you normally use?

Answer (score -1):

I tested by hand with Firefox and my proxy is OK.
This is my code.

```
    BrowserMobProxyServer proxyServer = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxyServer.setChainedProxy(new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
    proxyServer.chainedProxyAuthorization(username, password, AuthType.BASIC);
    proxyServer.start(0);

    ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
    ops.setProxy(ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxyServer));

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromePath);

    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
    driver.navigate().to("https://youtube.com");
```

My code not working.
I don't know what's the problem I met?